# Fixing shared part of code during feature development using GIT

Tags: git

I have the following problem.
Let's say I have *dev* branch of my solution. One day I come up with an idea to develop some new feature. So I create a new branch *feature/my-new-feature* from *dev*. During development of this feature I realize that it would be much easier to  create it (and also code would be generally better) if I refactor (maybe significantly) some shared services/classes or even interfaces.

What would you recommend to do in such case?

Yesterday I had such moment and I started to do these significant changes on my *feature/my-new-feature* branch. Unfortunately it was not the only feature branch that I had. After some rebasing, merging, duct-taping my repository became quite messy. Well, code works, but my commit history and branches graph... to be honest, even I don't know what is going on there.

If you find time to answer, please do it with examples of git commands. I'm not very proficient with git. Yesterday a few times I was surprised by results of my git actions.

Comment: I’d say don’t worry about “messy” history. And also please provide a [mcve] to your question. At the moment it sounds like you’re asking for some vague advice.

Comment: Problem is, you describe neither the specific commands you typed, nor the resulting "mess", so it's actually difficult to help you. Is it a somewhat complicated (but not unusual) refactoring history, or a real problematic mess? Is fonctionnality broken?

Comment: You're right, my problem is more general. I don't provide example, because honestly it's hard for me. I don't fully remember what I did yesterday with, there were a few rebases :) My question is rather about good practice in the described scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following work method which we use at work.
We start on the `master` branch which is our stable production. If we want to create a new feature we'll make a new branch `feature/whatever`. We make our changes and in the end rebase it on top of the latest `master` branch by using `git rebase -i origin/master`. This  opens an interactive mode in which you can easily rephrase, reorder, squash and even delete commits. This does however change your history and if you already pushed once to remote (on the feature branch) you need to force push your changes else git won't accept them.

After this we merge the branch onto the `master` branch.

If for some reason stuff has to be refactored we mostly choose to do this on a seperate clean branch (from the latest master) using the above method and merge that one first to master. One may also just commit those fixes on their local branch and than later add it in their feature branch again, however we tend to make our merges to master relative small.